# Search elements of a cursor in a collection

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

Initial problem: in Meteor, distinct is not implemented.

I have a collection of pilots:

```
Pilots : 
{
_id,
pilotcode : String,
name : String,
base : String
}
```

If i do

```
var pilotCursor = Pilots.find({})
```

I get all the pilots in a cursor;

Now I have a collection of flights:

```
Flights : 
{
...
pilot : String
...
}
```

For each `pilotcode` in `pilotCursor` i want to find if exits in at least a flight in `Flights`, then print the list of pilots found.
How can I do that?

Comment: [Please don't put tags in question titles](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe Felix solution won't work in Meteor but would do with Mongo. Meteor needs some extra touch to do aggregations, as far as I remember, something like this Meteor package: meteorhacks:aggregate

If you only need a list of pilots, I would map through the flights, push pilot ids uniquely to an array and then return the pilots:

I suppose pilot in Flights is the pilotcode in Pilots.

Pushing unique values to an array is something like this:

```
 const pilots = [];
    Flights.find().map((flight) => {
     if(pilots.indexOf(flight.pilot) === -1){
            pilots.push(flight.pilot);
        }
    })
   Pilots.find({ pilotcode: { $in: pilots } })
```

and expose the fields that you need.

Cursor mapping is one of the most efficient ways of querying Mongo DB.

Comment: Yes, pilot in Flights is the pilotcode in Pilots!

Actually, this works, and there's no need of `Pilots.find()`, I just need to return the `pilots` array. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you can achieve this with aggregation, no need fo distinct here.

1. first do a lookup between **Flights** and **Pilots** on `pilotcode` field
2. project the size of Flights founds for the pilot in a **`$project`** stage
3. filter out documents with no Flights
4. group all the pilotcode in a single array

here is the query :

```
db.Pilots.aggregate([
  {$lookup: {from: "Flights", localField: "pilotcode", foreignField: "pilot", as: "pilot"}},
  {$project: { pilotcode: 1, size: {$size: "$pilot"}}},
  {$match: {size: {$gt: 0}}},
  {$group: {_id: null, listPilotCode: {$push: "$pilotcode"}}}
])
```

this should output:

```
{"_id": null, "listPilotCode": [ pilotcode1, pilotcode2, ...]}
```